# Cross-Domain + iFrame Question

Tags: iframe, cookies, cross-domain

We are creating a "widget" for our site and wanted to ensure we have got this right.

I realize this all relates to X-Browser permissions but little worried about how this works with like Cookies and permissions ?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/), its a library that provides cross-domain communication, for instance between the parent page and the widget. One of the more advanced examples can be found at http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/methods.html

As easyXDM supports context, you can easily use cookies in the embedded window to provide authentication etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are tied to the domain, so any code in the parent will be unable to read cookies set in the site contained within the iframe I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi :) So this means that any data user does "outside" the iFrame cant be match to data inside the iframe and sent back to central.com?